# Postgres array malformed array literal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to copy an array into a table using Postgres and the error I am getting is:

```
     PG::InvalidTextRepresentation:
       ERROR:  malformed array literal: "["word one"]"
       DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
       CONTEXT:  COPY some_table, line 1, column keywords: "["word one"]"
```

What exactly does this mean? Do I have to change some things in the strings for it to work? I am using Ruby/Rails

Comment: Array literals in postgres use `{}`, not `[]` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT. So yours is indeed malformed.

Comment: So how should it look like in that case?
`"{"word one"}"`? 

I have basically 

```str = "["word one"]"```

Can I basically just do: 

```
str = str.gsub("[", "{").gsub("]", "}")
``` @SergioTulentsev thanks

Comment: I can't tell you how to fix code I haven't seen, but there are examples on that documentation page. So whatever string processing you do, make sure the end result looks one of those.

Comment: Is this a dupe of your previous question? If you're using Rails storing a literal array is handled by AR/AM. Are you trying to *convert* a string to an array?